# JS heap out of memory since migration angular 11 to 12,13 or 14

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I'm asking your help because of an JS heap out of memory when i want to start the local server since my migration from angular 11 to angular 12 (or 13 or 14, tried all versions with the same issus).

It append during the building phase

```
➜  easyevent-web git:(feature/migration-angular-12) ✗ npm start                                                              

> easyevent-web@1.0.0 start
> ng serve --configuration=dev --proxy-config proxy.conf.json

⠋ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...[HPM] Proxy created: /event-planner-api  ->  http://localhost:8080
[HPM] Subscribed to http-proxy events:  [ 'error', 'close' ]
⠋ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...WARNING: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div(30em, 14)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
12 │ $fa-li-width:         (30em / 14) !default;
   │                        ^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/font-awesome/scss/_variables.scss 12:24  @import
    node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss 6:9  root stylesheet

DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div(4em, 3)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

  ╷
6 │   font-size: (4em / 3);
  │               ^^^^^^^
  ╵
    node_modules/font-awesome/scss/_larger.scss 6:15       @import
    node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss 10:9  root stylesheet

DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div(3em, 4)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

  ╷
7 │   line-height: (3em / 4);
  │                 ^^^^^^^
  ╵
    node_modules/font-awesome/scss/_larger.scss 7:17       @import
    node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss 10:9  root stylesheet

DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div(18em, 14)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

  ╷
4 │   width: (18em / 14);
  │           ^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
    node_modules/font-awesome/scss/_fixed-width.scss 4:11  @import
    node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss 11:9  root stylesheet

DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div(2em, 14)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
14 │   top: (2em / 14);
   │         ^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/font-awesome/scss/_list.scss 14:9         @import
    node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss 12:9  root stylesheet

WARNING: 1 repetitive deprecation warnings omitted.

⠹ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_WORKER_OUT_OF_MEMORY]: Worker terminated due to reaching memory limit: JS heap out of memory
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at Worker.[kOnExit] (node:internal/worker:277:26)
    at Worker.<computed>.onexit (node:internal/worker:199:20)
Emitted 'error' event on Worker instance at:
    at Worker.[kOnExit] (node:internal/worker:277:12)
    at Worker.<computed>.onexit (node:internal/worker:199:20) {
  code: 'ERR_WORKER_OUT_OF_MEMORY'
}
```

The deprecation warning come from the using of font-anwsome package, it didn't change anything to remove that (already tried)

Increase the max old space size change nothing for me `--max_old_space_size=4096`

my ng v

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 12.2.18
Node: 16.17.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 8.15.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 12.2.16
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1202.18
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.18
@angular-devkit/core            12.2.18
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.18
@angular/cdk                    11.1.0
@angular/cli                    12.2.18
@schematics/angular             12.2.18
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.3.5
    
Warning: The current version of Node (16.17.0) is not supported by Angular.
```

(about the warning, i tried to update node because was recommanded on an other forum for a similar issue. node 16.17 is supported with angular 13 but in my case not work even with angular 13.

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "easyevent-web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --configuration=dev --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/localize": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.16",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.0.2",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^6.1.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^17.0.0",
    "angular-count-to": "0.0.3",
    "angularx-qrcode": "^11.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.22.11",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^11.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "sass": "^1.54.5",
    "screenfull": "^5.1.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.18",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.18",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.16",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.10.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.22",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^4.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "easyevent-web": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/easyevent-web",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/ngx-owl-carousel-o/lib/styles/prebuilt-themes/owl.carousel.min.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-owl-carousel-o/lib/styles/prebuilt-themes/owl.theme.default.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/assets/app.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "easyevent-web:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "browserTarget": "easyevent-web:build:dev"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "easyevent-web:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "easyevent-web:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "easyevent-web:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "easyevent-web:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "easyevent-web"
}
```

Everything is working very well with angular 11. The migration to a later version causes out of memories :(

Somebody had the same issus ? or do you see a solution ?

Thanks to all.

Comment: Did you get the solution? I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue upgrading to Angular 12, the problem is because `node-sass` is deprecated and instead it is used `sass`, so the problem is the SCSS code. In my case my project use a template and it has a lot of SCSS code.

To solve this I use the `sass-migrator` tool to migrate the SCSS code and fix the breacking changes, these are the [division operator](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div) and the way of importing modules has changed.

To solve the division operator issue I used:

```
sass-migrator division --verbose --migrate-deps **/*.scss
```

and for changing the module importing

```
sass-migrator module --verbose --migrate-deps **/*.scss
```

The migrator tool does not solve all the issues and those you will have to solve manually.

For those changes you can see the [Sass documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes)